# Implementation of resize jpeg image with javascript to a fixed size

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html5-canvas

Here is our implementation of a jpeg resize on client side to a fixed size of 1024 or 768. The work scenario is that a user selects an image (original image) he/she wants to upload (without display). If dimension of the original image is larger than 1024 or 768, then resize the image proportionally. The code below calculates the width and height of should-be and performs resize.

There are 2 `alert()` to show the image size before and after resize. We find that the file size is not reduced. What could be wrong with the code?

```
$(function(){
    $('#uploaded_file_file_for_upload').change(function(){
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var img, img_width = 0, img_height = 0, max_width = 1024, max_height = 768;
        var f = $(this)[0].files[0];  
        alert(f.size);
        if (f.type == 'image/jpeg' || f.type == 'image/jpg') {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
              img_width = this.width;  
              img_height = this.height;
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(f);
            if (img_width > max_width){
                img_height = Math.ceil(img_height * max_width / img_width);
                img_width = max_width;
            } else if (img_height > max_height) {
                img_width = Math.ceil(img_width * max_height / img_height);
                img_height = max_height;
            };
            resize(img, img_width, img_height);
            var f1 = $(this)[0].files[0]; 
            alert(f1.size);
        };

        function resize(image, width, height) {
          var mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          mainCanvas.width = width;
          mainCanvas.height = height;
          var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
          $('#uploaded_file_file_for_upload').attr('src', mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
        };

        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: After debugging, we have verified that the image resize works. The problem could be narrowed down to attaching the resized image back to the element #uploaded_file_file_for_upload which is the code line $('#uploaded_file_file_for_upload').attr('src', mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));

Answer (score 0):

check the `naturalWidth` from an image instead of css `width`

Comment: There  is no issue with image width.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.